# Herencia en java: superclase no devuelve arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, herencia, polimorfismo

En la superclase 'Muestra' creo un arraylist con objetos Double y la lleno por ventana JOptionPanel. Luego, en la subclase 'Pomedio' quiero calcular el promedio llamando al metodo getter 'getMuestra' pero devuelve una lista vacia! Probe este ultimo metodo directamente en el 'main' como muestro en el ejemplo y el progrma lanza una exepcion diciendome que la lista esta vacia! No se que problema conceptual puedo estar teniendo, gracias!

MAIN

```
public class Run {
public static void main(String[] args){
    // instancias para cada herramienta
    Muestra m =  new Muestra();
    Promedio p = new Promedio();

    m.crearMuestra();
    System.out.println(p.getPromedio());
}}
```

SUPERCLASE:

```
public class Muestra{
private ArrayList<Double> muestra;
private int tamanioMuestra;

public Muestra() {
    muestra = new ArrayList<>();
    tamanioMuestra = 0;
}

public void crearMuestra(){
    double numeros = 1;

    while(numeros != 0){
        numeros = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numero: "));
        if(numeros == 0)
            break;
        muestra.add(numeros);
    }
    if (this.getTamanioMuestra() != 0)
        System.out.println("Muestra guardada! Tamanio: " + this.getTamanioMuestra());
}

public int getTamanioMuestra(){
    tamanioMuestra = muestra.size();
    return tamanioMuestra;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getMuestra(){

    if(muestra.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("MUESTRA VACIA!");
    }else{
        return muestra;
    }
}}
```

SUBCLASE:

```
public class Promedio extends Muestra{
private double promedio;

public Promedio(){
    super();
    promedio = 0;
}

public double getPromedio(){
    for(Double n: super.getMuestra()){
        promedio += n;
    }
    promedio /= super.getTamanioMuestra();
    if(promedio == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No se pudo calcular promedio");
    }
    return promedio;
}}
```

Comment: Pero cuándo se llama al método crearMuestra() ? Si éste no se llama nunca, entonces nunca se agrega nada a la lista.

Comment: Lo hago en la clase 'main', instanciando las clases 'Muestra' y 'Promedio'. Logicamente primero llamo a crearMuestra() y luego getPromedio()

Comment: No tiene sentido usar herencia en ese caso. Un promedio no es una muestra pero si una operación que le puedes hacer a una muestra. Puedes codificar directamente el método `getPromedio` en la clase `Muestra`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu error es debido a una mala utilización de la *herencia*. Si `Promedio` extiende de `Muestra` no necesitas hacer esto:

```
Muestra m =  new Muestra(); 
Promedio p = new Promedio();
```

En tu concepción de la herencia piensas que `m` y `p` se van a entrecruzar porque sí, porque `Promedio` extiende de `Muestra` ... pero no, **`m` y `p` son dos instancias diferentes**. De hecho, al hacer esto:

```
System.out.println(p.getPromedio());
```

te lanza la excepción, porque **nunca has usado la instancia de `p` para nada.**

En este caso la herencia es mucho más simple de lo que crees: basta con crear la instancia de `Promedio` y usarla para crear la muestra. Entonces te preguntarás, ¿cómo llamo a `crearMuestra()` si es una instancia de `Promedio`? Pues precisamente, esa es una de las magias de la *herencia*: dado que `Promedio`  extiende de `Muestra` **hereda todos sus métodos y propiedades**. De modo que esto es totalmente posible y es lo que se debería hacer en este caso:

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Promedio p = new Promedio();
        p.crearMuestra();
        System.out.println(p.getPromedio());
    }
}
```

### Post Data

Con esto respondo al problema que presenta tu código. No obstante quiero señalar que la *herencia* no es algo sólo de conveniencia. A menudo se ve código donde se implementa *herencia* solamente por comodidad (para tener métodos de una clase en otra clase). La herencia es más que eso, uno de los pilares de la POO para expresar un modelo de datos robusto.

Generalmente en la *herencia*  se representa una jerarquía de clases que tienen elementos comunes entre ellos. En la *herencia* por lo general hay una relación digamos metafísica, relativa al *ser* de los objetos. Así, podemos decir que de una clase `Persona` podrían heredar clases como `Empleado, Vendedor, Atleta` porque son clases que compartirían propiedades que les son propias (metafísicamente... son parte del *ser* `Persona`), por ejemplo `nombre, sexo, fechaNacimiento, lugarNacimiento`. Pero una clase `Camion` o una clase `Bus` no debe heredar de `Persona`, porque una persona no es un `Vehiculo`.

Digo esto porque la *herencia* no es una cosa de conveniencia, sino de realidad constitutiva de los objetos que cada clase representa. Puede que en tu caso, `Promedio` no deba extender de `Muestra` a no ser que sean elementos que estén ligados a un nivel metafísico.

Comment: Para aportar un poco a lo que dices en tu entrada. La clave para la herencia es el verbo **ser**. Un `Empleado` **es** una `Persona`, un `Vendedor` **es** una `Persona`. Un `Bus` **es** un `Automotor`. En este caso, creo que, no solo los nombres de clase son confusos, sino que efectivamente un `Promedio` **no es** una `Muestra`. Más bien, se puede sacar un promedio de una muestra. En mi opinión no debiera existir una clase `Promedio`, sino un método `calcularPromedio` en alguna clase, quizás en la propia `Muestra`.

Comment: Excelente tu aporte, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Sumado a todo lo que ya te respondieron, recorda que todo lo que sea calculable no debería ser ni una clase ni un atributo, debe ser método.
El promedio esta trabajando con atributos de otra clase, lo cual no tiene sentido, el promedio debería ser un método de la clase Muestra, ya que esta mas cerca de los datos.
Otra cosa a observar es que estas usando herencia sin polimorfismo, lo cual no tiene sentido. Ignorando todo esto y haciendo de cuenta que lo planteado esta correcto te dejo el codigo para que funcione.

Para usar correctamente la Herencia tenes que plantear la clase Muestra de la siguiente manera:

```
public abstract class Muestra//cuando usas herencia tenes que hacer abstracta la clase
                             //madre o padre, para que no se pueda instanciar.
{
    protected ArrayList<Double> muestra;//aca lo declaro protected porque si no la clase hija no la ve. Esta es una señal de que hay algo malo en la herencia aplicada
                                        
    private int tamanioMuestra;

    public Muestra() {
        muestra = new ArrayList<>();
        tamanioMuestra = 0;
    }

    public void crearMuestra() {
        double numeros = 1;

        while (numeros != 0) {
            numeros = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numero: "));
            if (numeros == 0) {
                break;
            }
            muestra.add(numeros);
        }
        if (this.getTamanioMuestra() != 0) {
            System.out.println("Muestra guardada! Tamanio: " + this.getTamanioMuestra());
        }
    }

    public int getTamanioMuestra() {
        tamanioMuestra = muestra.size();
        return tamanioMuestra;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getMuestra() {

        if (muestra.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("MUESTRA VACIA!");
        } else {
            return muestra;
        }
    }

    public double getPromedio() // deberias crear un metodo general el cual se encarga de 
                                // calcular el promedio, y en la clase promedio solo
                                // lo tenes que modificar si algo cambia
    {
        return 0; //este método no hace nade pero debe existir para que compile. Esta debería ser la primera señal de que estas implementando mal la herencia, tener métodos vacios que no hacen nada
    }
}
```

Tu clase promedio deberia ser asi:

```
public class Promedio extends Muestra
{
    private double promedio;


    public Promedio()   
{
    super();
    promedio = 0;
}

public double getPromedio()
{
    for(double n: muestra)
    {
        promedio += n;
    }
    promedio /= super.getTamanioMuestra();
    if(promedio == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No se pudo calcular promedio");
    }
    return promedio;
}}
```

y ahora el main te queda asi:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
   
        Muestra promedio = new Promedio(); //Aca la magia del poliformismo, yo declaro el promedio del tipo padre pero llamo al new del hijo.

        promedio.crearMuestra();
        System.out.println(promedio.getPromedio());
    }
```